# Convert JSON like string to python dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Now I have a string like json from http requests, but the keys are not in the format of string. For example,

```
    >>> data_string = """
        {
        server_id: 1, 
        server_status: 200,
        client: "client2",
        content: [ {id: 0, info: "info0"}, {id: 2, info: "info2"} ]
        }
    """
```

I want to format it by JSON for easily extracting fields of the data string. I have a solution that using eval in python,

```
    eval(data_string, type('Dummy', (dict,), dict(__getitem__ = lambda s, n: n))())
```

And it gives me the right data:

```
   {'server_id': 1, 'server_status': 200, 'client': 'client2', 'content': [{'id': 0, 'info': 'info0'}, {'id': 2, 'info': 'info2'}]}
```

Please help me understand the tricks of the code. Thx.

PS: I have tried json but failed. However, yaml.load(data_string) works.

Comment: something wrong with your eval code its not executing throwing

Comment: May I ask where you got that `eval(...)` code from? I can't decide if I want to up- or downvote it, but I want to make sure it comes with appropriate warning labels...

Comment: If YAML works, what is then the problem?

Comment: @Godfray common mab reply our doubts

Comment: I've run into this problem in the advertising industry with the collection and storage of dictionaries etc from the FaceBook marketing APIs. One common issue is that these strings we're speaking about are often simply nested dictionaries within other dictionaries. Improper parsing and storage of those dictionaries leads to the problem we have here. This is not an issue if you have a small dataset but using `eval()` to parse these strings into python dictionaries is a computationally inefficient process and can blow out your processing time. Consider if you can amend the collection process.

Comment: .... to ensure that nested strings are not stored in columns or cells within dataframes or DB tables such that they are converted to strings.

Comment: @Rawing, I got that code from an open source [project](https://github.com/waditu/tushare/blob/master/tushare/stock/newsevent.py) see Line 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
eval(data_string, type('Dummy', (dict,), dict(__getitem__ = lambda s, n: n))())
```

is a *very* ugly way to do the same as

```
class Dummy(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key

globals_obj = Dummy()
eval(data_string, globals_obj)
```

and then this `globals_obj` is passed into the `globals` parameter of `eval`. The `globals` must be a *mapping* object that maps names to values. Now when the `eval` encounters a variable being used, it will consult *this* mapping object, as if by `globals_obj['variable_name']`. The `__getitem__` method simply returns the given key as a value, therefore `globals_obj[42]` -> `42`, `globals_obj[None]`-> `None`  and so forth.

This all is very insecure - if the server wants to be malicious the api couldreturn code like `__import__('os').system('execute an evil command')`.

---

If this is *JavaScript* but not *JSON*, you might be able to use the [`demjson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demjson/2.2.4) module in `strict=False` mode. It is certainly better than using `eval` and might be better than using YAML as [YAML parsers might be insecure](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_avoid-dangerous-input-parsing-libraries.html). [And these bugs might be easily remotely exploitable](https://arp242.net/weblog/yaml_probably_not_so_great_after_all.html).

```
>>> import demjson
>>> data_string = """
...         {
...         server_id: 1, 
...         server_status: 200,
...         client: "client2",
...         content: [ {id: 0, info: "info0"}, {id: 2, info: "info2"} ]
...         }
...     """
>>> demjson.decode(data_string, strict=False)
{'server_id': 1, 'server_status': 200, 'client': 'client2', 'content': [{'id': 0, 'info': 'info0'}, {'id': 2, 'info': 'info2'}]}
```